# Security question about managed triggers and classes

Tags: apex, managed-package

I understand that managed triggers and packages protect the intellectual property of developers, but how can I verify that this code is not "stealing" data from my org?

The data that we handle is sensitive and although we have signed specific paperwork prohibiting the app developer from taking our data, how can I be sure?

What logs should I be checking to make sure no external APIs are being called and that no data is being emailed/taken within those managed classes?

Answer (score 4):

As an org administrator when you install the appexchange , you will be requested to approve prompts for remote access settings that will give you a fair amount of idea of what external points the app is touching .

Also you might want to play with the app in trial org or sandbox and double check all integration points and take a written agreement on data extraction touch points

Comment: Thanks, I have checked the remote site settings, nothing suspicious. I failed to mention that this software intergration is being developed and installed by a third party company, this is not something that we are installing ourselves, and that this is a fairly expensive $20k+ solution, not just a random install from the appexchange.

Comment: I would request you to ask the company to go through formal salesforce security review process .Security review of an application ensures all the security risks are mitigated .

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by earlier answers, Remote Site Settings need to be approved for apex to make callouts. Beyond that:

- Triggers cannot directly make callouts, and need either scheduled apex, @future, or Queueable to do this, which all leave AsyncApexJob entries. Even though you can't see the contents a ton of these would raise eyebrows at least.
- Push upgrades of new managed package versions automatically inactivate new Remote Site Settings, and require manual activation post-install.
- The "easiest" way to exfiltrate data from the org is using the browser, like loading an invisible iframe that includes data as paramers, and visualforce markup is available to browse.
- Basic metadata about email sent is logged and can be requested in CSV format via setup.
- AppExchange security review all but guarantees that at the time of review the app didn't do this (without explicit consent of the org admin). The security review folks apply rules similar to those imposed on internal Salesforce development. Not 100% bulletproof either, but major app changes cause security re-reviews to come sooner (generally).

Comment: "visualforce markup is available to browse" - yes but managed VF components are hidden, just like classes. So you'd have to check generated HTML, maybe watch out for JavaScript requests...

Answer (score 2):

Remote Site Settings control which endpoints can be used from Apex Callouts (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=configuring_remoteproxy.htm&language=en&type=0). These are required for any callout (even to Salesforce from Salesforce) so review these in your org and you will have an idea of which external endpoints can be used.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few technical ways that developers could sneak in ways to send data invisibly to steal data, such as invisible iframes to untrusted sites. It's simply the nature of the platform. However, the majority of developers on the AppExchange have already been through a security review, which includes live people reviewing their code to make sure that they're not doing anything sneaky. Apps which are not listed on the AppExchange and do not have the AppExchange Security badge (whatever they're calling it these days), have not been officially reviewed and could be stealing data. However, an app found to be doing so would most likely be shut down immediately so it could cause no further harm.

To date, I do not know of a single incident of a developer that's gotten away with data theft. As a matter of practicality, it simply isn't worth the trouble of producing an app that people would want to install and yet have a backdoor data theft system in place. While salesforce.com does recommend that you use only security-reviewed apps, they will not hesitate to shut down an app that violates data security and report the developers to the appropriate authorities for violating relevant laws.

At the end of the day, it's probably best to use the due diligence you'd use for installing software on your computer. Install apps from trusted developers that have been through security reviews, instead of installing random apps that have not be reviewed or published on the AppExchange, and make sure that you use the appropriate security controls so that apps only have as much API access as necessary to function correctly. As long as you keep your list of installed apps to a minimum, and then only those that have passed a security review, you'll reduce the risk of data theft considerably.

Comment: This is software being developed specifically for us, this is not something that we are installing from the appexchange, and if it is, it's being done by a third party company. I have checked the remote sites setting, and everything seems to be ok.

Comment: @dave10205 A developer could still sneak in other ways to get data out, such as sending an email with data in it, or posting to an iframe, etc. If you're not installing from the app exchange, you might want to at least do a cursory security analysis using the [Force.com Source Scanner](https://security.secure.force.com/security/tools/forcecom/scanner) for potential red flags.